# jquery spservices getlistitems

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, spservices

im trying to get listitems from a sharepoint list using jquery spservices.
but it doesnt return any listitems.
here's the code, anyone knows what's wrong?

```
var _query = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>maandag</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";

$().SPServices({
    operation: 'GetListItems',
    async: false,
    listName: 'OpeningsTijden',
    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Title' /><FieldRef Name='Time' /></ViewFields>",
    CAMLQuery: _query,
      completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    alert(xData.responseText);
                    $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 

         alert('yessir');

                        });                
                    }

        });
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What does responseText look like? Are you getting any script errors?

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to use the debug feature to ensure your request is working:

```
if (Status == "success") {
  alert(xData.responseXML);
}else {
  var out = $().SPServices.SPDebugXMLHttpResult({
  node: xData.responseXML,
  outputId: myRequests
});

$('#myRequests').html(out);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your code, works perfect :) maybe you spelled your list name wrong or something, i copied and used it. Worked first time

Comment: Is there a good method to assure that the list name is correct as what SharePoint sees it called and what was last entered for the name do not always align.

Answer (score 0):

1- Check try to remove filter from your query and see the result if it brings the data means your filter is incorrect or the column in your filter is different.

2- if still it did not returned any values there might be issue with your list

3- Usually lists which are migrated from SP 2007 they does not support SPServices features
try to create new list and try your code.